# ReactNative typescript: Axios is not allowing to pass file data FormData to upload file

Tags: typescript, react-native, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I am building a Mobile application using ReactNative and TypeScript. I am trying to upload file using Axios so that I need to make `multipart/form-data` request. In javascript I can pass the file data to the form data request like this.

```
formData.append(`image_file`, {
                uri: form.image_file.path,
                name: form.image_file.filename,
                type: form.image_file.mime
            });
```

Now, I am trying to do the same for TypeScript. But when I pass the same object in the TypeScript, I am getting the following compilation error.

[image]

[image]

So that I had to cast the object into `any` type as follow.

[image]

How can I fix that error without casting the object into `any` because I am not a fan of using `any` type.